# Re-Consume Kafka messages from a given time

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am using Confluent.Kafka .NET client version 1.3.0. I would like to start consuming messages from a given time onwards.

To do so, I could use `OffsetsForTimes` to get the desired offset and `Commit` that offset for that partition:

```
private void SetOffset()
{
    const string Topic = "myTopic";
    const string BootstrapServers = "server1, server2";

    var adminClient = new AdminClientBuilder(
        new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "bootstrap.servers", BootstrapServers },
            { "security.protocol", "sasl_plaintext" },
            { "sasl.mechanisms", "PLAIN" },
            { "sasl.username", this.kafkaUsername },
            { "sasl.password", this.kafkaPassword }
        }).Build();

    var consumer = new ConsumerBuilder<byte[], byte[]>(
        new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "bootstrap.servers", BootstrapServers },
            { "group.id", this.groupId },
            { "enable.auto.commit", "false" },
            { "security.protocol", "sasl_plaintext" },
            { "sasl.mechanisms", "PLAIN" },
            { "sasl.username", this.kafkaUsername },
            { "sasl.password", this.kafkaPassword }
        }).Build();

    // Timestamp to which the offset should be set to
    var timeStamp = new DateTime(2020, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

    var newOffsets = new List<TopicPartitionOffset>();
    var metadata = adminClient.GetMetadata(Topic, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
    foreach (var topicMetadata in metadata.Topics)
    {
        if (topicMetadata.Topic == Topic)
        {
            foreach (var partitionMetadata in topicMetadata.Partitions.OrderBy(p => p.PartitionId))
            {
                var topicPartition = new TopicPartition(topicMetadata.Topic, partitionMetadata.PartitionId);

                IEnumerable<TopicPartitionOffset> found = consumer.OffsetsForTimes(
                    new[] { new TopicPartitionTimestamp(topicPartition, new Timestamp(timeStamp, TimestampType.CreateTime)) },
                    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

                newOffsets.Add(new TopicPartitionOffset(topicPartition, new Offset(found.First().Offset)));
            }
        }
    }

    consumer.Commit(newOffsets);

    // Consume messages
    consumer.Subscribe(Topic);
    var consumerResult = consumer.Consume();
    // process message
    //consumer.Commit(consumerResult);
}
```

This works fine if I want to *skip* messages and jump to a given offset if the offset to which I would like to jump is *after* the last committed message.

However, the above approach won't work if the given timestamp is *before* the timestamp of the last committed message. In the above code, if the `timeStamp` is before the timestamp of the last committed message, then `OffsetsForTimes` will return the offset of that last committed message + 1. Even if I manually set the offset to a lower offset, then `consumer.Commit(newOffsets)` seems to have no effect and I am getting the first uncommitted message when consuming.

Is there a way to achive this from the code?

Comment: You can always set the offset value manually. Go to your stream, find the offset that fits for you and start from there. If it helps to solve your problem. No need to fetch offset by specific DateTime

Comment: @OlegI can you please elaborate on how exactly this is done? Just to be clear, I do want to start consuming messages from a given time even if they have been consumed and committed already.

Comment: I can explain how it works and you may figure the solution on your own. Kafka contains system topics. One of the system topics contains key-value group-id -> offset value. If you start consuming from different offset because you hardcoded it or fetched using DateTime after first commit it will ovveride old values. And you can't restore prviously commited offsets

Comment: Commit has no effect on what is your consume is currently polling. You have to seek to offset which changes to new offset from where consume can poll. Also note you can seek only to the assigned partitions meaning you need to assign partitions first before seek.

Comment: @user2683814  Ah didn't know that, thanks! So part of my question was how to get the offset of the first message whose timestamp is after a given time, with the above approach, `OffsetsForTimes`, if the given time is prior to the timestamp of the last committed message, I would get the last committed message + 1. Also, even when I try to `Seek` with an offset prior to the last committed message offset, and then Consume, I still get the next message after the last committed message, what I am missing here?

Comment: You're welcome. Could you please show me code how and when you are seeking ? Are you using subscribe and seek or assign and seek ?

Comment: Thinking more about it  - You could register seek callback in the subscribe so you can adjust the offset as needed. So this way you can change either using output from offsetfortimes or some random offset. I will see how this could be done using .net library but this should give you some idea.

Comment: It really depends what library supports behind the scene. Assign/Seek/Consume will definitely work for any offsets but you will lose the whole consumer rebalance and group subscription if you don’t use subscribe. I think for your use case you would need both.

Comment: @havij, I am facing issues in reading kafka msg by DateTime range. 

Could you post the final working code here?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 5):

You can do it if you assign to each partition and state the offset from which to start reading.

this is how you get the list of topic partitions:

```
public static List<TopicPartition> GetTopicPartitions(string bootstrapServers, string topicValue) {
    var tp = new List<TopicPartition>();
    using (var adminClient = new AdminClientBuilder(new AdminClientConfig { BootstrapServers = bootstrapServers }).Build()) {
        var meta = adminClient.GetMetadata(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
        meta.Topics.ForEach(topic => {
            if (topic.Topic == topicValue) {
                foreach (PartitionMetadata partition in topic.Partitions) {
                    tp.Add(new TopicPartition(topic.Topic, partition.PartitionId));
                }
            }
        });
    }
    return tp;
}
```

This is how you find the offset of a particular time:

```
List<TopicPartition> topic_partitions = frmMain.GetTopicPartitions(mBootstrapServers, txtTopic.Text);

using (var consumer = new ConsumerBuilder<Ignore, string>(cfg).Build()) {
    consumer.Assign(topic_partitions);

    List<TopicPartitionTimestamp> new_times = new List<TopicPartitionTimestamp>();
    foreach (TopicPartition tp in topic_partitions) {
        new_times.Add(new TopicPartitionTimestamp(tp, new Timestamp(dtpNewTime.Value)));
    }

    List<TopicPartitionOffset> seeked_offsets = consumer.OffsetsForTimes(new_times, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(40));
    string s = "";
    foreach (TopicPartitionOffset tpo in seeked_offsets) {
        s += $"{tpo.TopicPartition}: {tpo.Offset.Value}\n";
    }
    Console.WriteLine(s);
    consumer.Close();
}
```

This is how you consume by assigning to all topic partition and specific offsets:

```
using (var consumer =
    new ConsumerBuilder<string, string>(config)
        .SetErrorHandler((_, e) => Log($"Error: {e.Reason}"))
        .Build()) {
    consumer.Assign(seeked_offsets);

    try {
        while (true) {
            try {
                var r = consumer.Consume(cancellationToken);
                // do something with r
            } catch (ConsumeException e) {
                //Log($"Consume error: {e.Error.Reason}");
            }
        }
    } catch (OperationCanceledException) {
        //Log("Closing consumer.");
        consumer.Close();
    }
}
```

The other option, if you insist in applying this to the consumer group, would be to reset the consumer group and use your code, or to create a new consumer group.

Comment: When I run the above code in asp.net core,  

I am getting below error , %4|1632063373.082|ASSIGN|rdkafka#consumer-1| [thrd:main]: Group "1": application *assign() call failed: Changes to the current assignment must be made using incremental_assign() or incremental_unassign() when rebalance protocol type is COOPERATIVE
Unhandled exception. Confluent.Kafka.KafkaException: Local: Erroneous state

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert but i'm going to try to explain how you could do it.

In first place, we have to mention subscribe and assign methods.

When you use subscribe, you pass a one or more topics. With this, a list of partitions of each topics are assigned to the consumer depending of the number of consumers in its group. A topic partition is an object formed by the topic name and the partition number.

```
consumer.Subscribe(Topic);
```

You can use assign to pass the partitions of which the consumer will read. This method does not use the consumer's group management functionality (where no need of group.id)
If i'm not wrong, in assign method you can specify the initial offset.

```cs
consumer.Assign(topicName, 0, new Offset(lastConsumedOffset));
consumer.Assign(topicPartition, new Offset(lastConsumedOffset));
```

Another option is to use seek() method to set the offset

```cs
consumer.Seek(topicPartitionOffset);
```

If you are going to mix subscribe and assign remember that you have to use unsubscribe before.

> Another option, if you want to re-consume all the messages is create a
>   consumer in a new different consumer group.

## EXAMPLE (TO REVIEW)

I'm leaving you and example for now, i will check it later.
I have done the example in java because i'm more familiar with it.
In this example, i don't use subscribe, i use assign.
First topic partitions are retrieved, we set a start datetime to read messages from, we create a map specifing that that datetime for each partition.

With the created map we get the offset of each partition on the specified datetime with offsetsForTimes method. With the offset of each partition we use seek to move to that offset on each partitions and finally we consume the messages.

I don't have time now to check the code, but i will do it. 
I hope it helps.

```java
        AdminClient client = AdminClient.create(getAdminClientProperties());
        KafkaConsumer<String, GenericRecord> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, GenericRecord>(
                getConsumerProperties());

        String TOPIC = "topic";

        // get info of all partitions of a topic
        List<PartitionInfo> partitionsInfo = consumer.partitionsFor(TOPIC);

        // create TopicPartition list
        Set<TopicPartition> partitions = new HashSet<>();
        for (PartitionInfo p : partitionsInfo) {
            partitions.add(new TopicPartition(p.topic(), p.partition()));
        }

        // Consumer will read from all partitions
        consumer.assign(partitions);
        DateTime timeToStartReadMessagesFrom = new DateTime(2020, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0);

        Map<TopicPartition, Long> timestamps = new HashMap<>();
        for (TopicPartition tp : partitions) {
            timestamps.put(tp, timeToStartReadMessagesFrom.getMillis());
        }
        // get the offset for that time in each partition
        Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndTimestamp> offsets = consumer.offsetsForTimes(timestamps);
        for (TopicPartition tp : partitions) {
            consumer.seek(tp, offsets.get(tp).offset());
        }

        while (true) {
            final ConsumerRecords<String, GenericRecord> consumerRecords = consumer.poll(1000);
            // do something
            break;
        }
        consumer.close();
        System.out.println("DONE");
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but two things: 1- part of my question was how to get the offset of the first message whose timestamp is after a given time (again, my approach above won't work if the given time is prior to the timestamp of the last committed message). 2- Even when I try `Seek` with an offset prior to the last committed message offset, and then `Consume`, I still get the next message after the last commited message, am I missing something here?